# how to add user-data for the second time in an ec2 instance through java sdk

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

i am trying to add user-data for the second time after stopping the instance and while restarting i want to pass some user data again for this i am using

```
public InstanceStatusResponse startEc2Instance(AmazonEC2 ec2Client, String instanceId) {

    BlockDeviceMapping blockDeviceMappings = new BlockDeviceMapping();

    blockDeviceMappings.setDeviceName(storageProperties.getDeviceName());
    System.out.println("vatsal");
    ModifyInstanceAttributeRequest modifyInstanceAttributeRequest = new ModifyInstanceAttributeRequest()
            .withUserData(userdata())


    ModifyInstanceAttributeRequest request = new ModifyInstanceAttributeRequest();
    request.setUserData(userdata());

    System.out.println(modifyInstanceAttributeRequest.withUserData(userdata()));
    System.out.println(modifyInstanceAttributeRequest.getUserData());

    StartInstancesRequest startInstancesRequest = new StartInstancesRequest().withInstanceIds(instanceId);
    ec2Client.startInstances(startInstancesRequest);
    //System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Starting the ec2 instance");


    return instanceStatusResponse(ec2Client, instanceId);
```

}

and i am passing some userdata which also i am using base64 encoding as per demand but i am not able to send values to that ec2 machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have posted is not really clear.
You have created `modifyInstanceAttributeRequest` and `request`, however you don't seem to be using them.

Nevertheless, a typically ec2 instance will not run the user-data script on reboots. The user-data scripts are only run at the first boot of the instance.

[See this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) about user data and run only on first boot.

> **Important**
>
> By default, user data scripts and cloud-init directives run only
>   during the first boot cycle when an instance is launched. However, you
>   can configure your user data scripts and cloud-init directives to run
>   every time the instance is restarted from a stopped state. For more
>   information, see How can I execute user data after the initial launch
>   of my EC2 instance? in the AWS Knowledge Center

To be able to to re-run user-data scripts on start of an ec2 instance, see [this kb article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/) from AWS.

Comment: Hey  so in the article to re run the user data scripts they have also suggested to use modify instance attribute and that is only one I am using too , I am setting the user data , so it should work right ?

Comment: like i mentioned above you have not used your requests objects you have just created them. Where do you use them?

Answer (score 0):

although i was looking for a approach from modify attribute request , but i found a good way to use user- data scripts on every stop and restart instances by creating an ami of an ec2-instance which has all the scripts in their rc.local file . You cannot make changes to rc.local directly , you need to become first a root user , then only you will be able to access it , and this file runs after all user-data scripts and cloud-init scripts are executed.